# HTML - login system without PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication

I know the answer will probably be no, but I am creating a set of web pages for a Yr 9, IST assignment. The web page cannot be hosted & our marker isn't smart enough to use a virtual server.

Is JS or any other HTML compatible programming language capable of creating an offline login system?(It needs to be able to interact with multiple pages)

Again the answer is probably no but I'm curious to find any answers.

Thanks, Lachlan

Comment: do a system login with JS is possible but what kind of interaction between pages are you expecting ??

Comment: say you had something only accessible by a user logged in, hiding that content. It can just be if a user is logged in, no individual settings or anything.

Comment: @PacMan How would it be possible without a database and retrieving data from that database to validate info? You can't hard code it because that's a security issue. You can't someone have it on an external source because that'll call for queries. Not sure how you'd do it. Any way you do it, there'd be a security vulnerability

Comment: An offline login system has no security unless you were hashing the passwords somehow, so might as well do it directly in JavaScript. But then you can simply bypass the login system by going to wherever the page was supposed to go if the login was successful. Then-again if they had to run a server, they'd have access to everything anyways... so security aside, it's possible...

Comment: @LachlanJansen sorry but you can not cause those pages could be accessible without any permission or test on session those actions are not supported with JS if your marker is the only user of that app and it'l locally you can handle something out with JS else you're supposed to use PHP or some server side languague

Comment: Thankyou everyone, security is not an issue, i just need it to handle Username + Password. Is creating and reading multiple lines of a text document possible with JS

Comment: No, client side JavaScript has no local file access.  You'd have to put everything in a single file.

Comment: JScript, Internet Explorer's version of JavaScript, when ran offline, has local file access via ActiveXObject. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx But you shouldn't need file access in the first place. If you need to write something, use cookies, if you need to read something, such as from a database of passwords, make it a JS file then insert it into the document. If you need the power to add users, look into local storage.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently already know the answer:  no!  The credentials ***absolutely*** need to be validated on another system.

A login system implies securing a portion of the site by validating some user credentials to give them access to a specific portion.  While it would be easy to fake a login system in JavaScript, it would be very far from secure as anyone who knows how to look at the page's source code would get access to whatever they want.

Comment: My teacher thought that having an expandable text box was amazing, I don't think she'll look into the security. Thanks, I do see your point :)

Comment: not even with some sort of distributed database where no one has the full database by using peer to peer webrtc ?

Comment: @shadownrun:  Obviously not since the user can locally modify the script to ignore any security.